# Can more gitpitch presentations be created on the same github repository?

Tags: github, gitpitch

Since the a gitpitch presentation is displayed at the location
`https://gitpitch.com/user-name/repository-name`
only one gitpitch presentation can be created per repository.

I would like to use gitpitch to create more presentations, but it feels like creating a new repository for every presentation is too much.
Is there any way to go around this limitation?

E.g. display presentations with a more specific URL, something like
`https://gitpitch.com/user-name/repository-name/sub-folder`

Comment: There currently doesn't seem to be support for sub-folders directly, but it's possible to have branches: `https://gitpitch.com/user/repo/branch`. See [Asset Sharing](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/wiki/Asset-Sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple presentations in a single branch within repo. You do not have to branch for each new presentation.

Take a look at the [Asset Sharing](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/wiki/Asset-Sharing) and [Modular Markdown](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/wiki/Modular-Markdown) pages on the GitPitch Wiki for details. The asset sharing page explains how you can create and share any number of presentations within in a single repo. The modular markdown page explains how you can break the markdown for your presentations into multiple files and even share markdown files across multiple presentations.

Comment: Still, it does not work... I have the structure
repo-root
|- folder-one
   |- PITCHME.md
|- folder-two
   |- PITCHME.md

And I try to access them with the url:
https://gitpitch.com/user/repo-root/branch?p=folder-one

... and I get a 404 error :(... Any clues? I'm on the master branch, could that be it?

Comment: Ahh... replaced "branch" with "master" and it worked :)). 
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Had a hard time finding the answer in the documentation but this worked for me. If you put your `PITCHME.md` file in your `subfolder`, then use the following path.

```
https://gitpitch.com/user/repo/branch?p=subfolder
```

with the key component of placing `?p=subfolder` after the `branch` name.

More can be found here https://gitpitch.com/docs/git/branch-many-slideshows